# Is there a possibility to merge 2 dataframes in R, keeping only unique results with one of the columns as the dependency for which results are kept

Tags: r, join, merge

I know the question is confusing, but I don't know how to formulate it better. I have 11 xls lists that contain GOTerm IDS in the format

```
ID   Category   Colour
```

These lists all in all contain about 130k IDS however, only 26k of those are unique.

I built a ranking of the 11 lists by category. What I need now is a way to merge List 11 with List 10 and for any ID that is in both lists, I want to keep the ID with the lower category number (in this example category 10) and the matching colour.

Preferably I'd like to do this in one script/ combined lines of code for all lists.

Example

List11

| ID | Category | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category11 | red |
| 2 | Category11 | red |
| 3 | Category11 | red |

List10

| ID | Category | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category10 | blue |
| 2 | Category10 | blue |
| 4 | Category10 | blue |

And my ideal merged result would look like this:

| ID | Category | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category10 | blue |
| 2 | Category10 | blue |
| 3 | Category11 | red |
| 4 | Category10 | blue |

And then the same thing for the new list vs. List 9, that result vs list 8 and so on

Comment: Question is quite confusing indeed. Anyhow, are you trying to retain only column10 across all the lists or does it change to category9 when you merge it with list9 and son?

Comment: If an ID is in List 11 10 and 9 than in the final list it should say category 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach of your problem. funcxtional explanation of the code is in the comments of the code.

In this solution, there is no merging of the different tables. In stead, they are rowbound together and per ID only the rows that appear first are kept.

I do not know how you have read in your excels, but if you read in you excels using something like `L <- lapply(myexcelfiles, readxl::read_excel)`, then your excel files are already inside a list and you can skip some of the lines below and start with the line `DT <- rbindlist(L, id = "ListId")`.

```
library(data.table)
# Sample data
List11 <- fread("ID     Category    colour
1   Category11  red
2   Category11  red
3   Category11  red")
List10 <- fread("ID     Category    colour
1   Category10  blue
2   Category10  blue
4   Category10  blue")

# Add the items (in order!) to a list
L <- list(List10, List11)
# Put the list in one large data.table
# Get a ListId from the position in the list
DT <- rbindlist(L, id = "ListId")
#    ListId ID   Category colour
# 1:      1  1 Category10   blue
# 2:      1  2 Category10   blue
# 3:      1  4 Category10   blue
# 4:      2  1 Category11    red
# 5:      2  2 Category11    red
# 6:      2  3 Category11    red
# Only keep rows with the minimum ListId by ID
# and drop the ListId column afterward and order on ID
final <- setorder(DT[ , .SD[which.min(ListId)], by = ID][, ListId := NULL], ID)
#    ID   Category colour
# 1:  1 Category10   blue
# 2:  2 Category10   blue
# 3:  3 Category11    red
# 4:  4 Category10   blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me share this example, which should give you an idea of the steps using basic R.

First, let's create these two dataframes. (A `list` is something different in R.)

```
list11 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                     category = "Category11",
                     colour = "red")
list10 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 4),
                     category = "Category10",
                     colour = "blue")
```

This results in:

```
> list11
  id   category colour
1  1 Category11    red
2  2 Category11    red
3  3 Category11    red
> list10
  id   category colour
1  1 Category10   blue
2  2 Category10   blue
3  4 Category10   blue
```

Next, you could join both data frames by ID:

```
joined <- merge(x = list10, y = list11, by = "id", all = TRUE)
```

which will give you:

```
> joined
  id category.x colour.x category.y colour.y
1  1 Category10     blue Category11      red
2  2 Category10     blue Category11      red
3  3       <NA>     <NA> Category11      red
4  4 Category10     blue       <NA>     <NA>
```

The idea is that we take everyting which exists in the x-columns. Only if there's nothing (= `<NA>`) then we check the y-columns. This is what we do using the `is.na()`function:

```
new10 <- joined[!is.na(joined$category.x), c("id", "category.x", "colour.x")]
new11 <- joined[is.na(joined$category.x), c("id", "category.y", "colour.y")]
> new10
  id category.x colour.x
1  1 Category10     blue
2  2 Category10     blue
4  4 Category10     blue
> new11
  id category.y colour.y
3  3 Category11      red
```

The `merge` function above gave us new column names, so we have to set them back:

```
colnames(new10) <- c("id", "category", "colour")
colnames(new11) <- c("id", "category", "colour")
```

Now both data frames have the same column names and we can stick them together again using:

```
> final <- rbind(new10, new11)
> final
  id   category colour
1  1 Category10   blue
2  2 Category10   blue
4  4 Category10   blue
3  3 Category11    red
```

Finally we can sort, if we want to do that:

```
> final <- final[order(final$id), ]
> final
  id   category colour
1  1 Category10   blue
2  2 Category10   blue
3  3 Category11    red
4  4 Category10   blue
```

To process all your XLSs you could either create a loop around it or use a list of data frames and `apply` over it.